# Creating Virtual Fields based on condtions

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Good day. :) I'm new to cakePHP so please bear with me.

I have a Model Student. Student has an attribute status which is an integer. I want to create virtual fields based on a Student's status.

Example:

```
 Status     VirtualField
    1        new student
    2        new student - transferee
    3        old student - shiftee
    4        old student
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify what RDMS you're using, I'm assuming MySQL

### Using a fixed strings

If you want to have this virtualField based on *fixed strings*, you can achieve this via a [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) in MySQL and use that to define the virtualField

```
$this->MyModel->virtualFields['status_title'] = "
    CASE 
        WHEN status = 1 THEN 'new student'
        WHEN status = 2 THEN 'new student - transferee'
        WHEN status = 3 THEN 'old student - shiftee'
        WHEN status = 4 THEN 'old student'
        ELSE 'unkown status'
    END
";
```

Or, to define it inside the Model itself;

```
class Student extends AppModel {

    public $virtualFields = array(
        'status_title' => "
            CASE 
                WHEN status = 1 THEN 'new student'
                WHEN status = 2 THEN 'new student - transferee'
                WHEN status = 3 THEN 'old student - shiftee'
                WHEN status = 4 THEN 'old student'
                ELSE 'unkown status'
            END
        ",
    );
}
```

### Using a separate table

In my answer, I'm assuming you're trying to use **fixed strings** for the titles. It's better to use a separate database-table to store the status and (optionally) create a virtualField for that;

Your Student model; app/Model/Student.php

class Student extends AppModel {

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Status' => array(
        'type' => 'INNER',
    ),
};
```

}

Your Status model; app/Model/Status.php

class Status extends AppModel {

```
public $useTable = 'statuses';

public $hasMany = array(
    'Student',
};
```

}

Your database-tables should be like this;

students;

```
id         primary key, autonumber
status_id  id
name       varchar(50),
-- etc.
```

statuses

```
id         primary key, autonumber
name       varchar(50),
```

When retrieving a Student, the Status should automatically be included;

For example

```
$data = $this->Student->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Student.id',
        'Student.name',
        'Status.name',
    ),
    'recursive' => 1,
));
```

Should return all Students and their Status

If you want to add the status-name as a 'virtual field' and have it included inside the 'Student' array-index;

```
// Create the virtual field
$this->Student->virtualFields['status_name'] = 'Status.name';

// And use it inside your query
$data = $this->Student->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Student.id',
        'Student.name',
        'Student.status_name',
    ),
    'recursive' => 1,
));
```

Comment: If using the strings, where do i have to put it? in the Model or in the  Controller?

Comment: That depends; If you *always* want that virtualField to be present, define it inside the Model (I just added an example). However, I **strongly advice you to store the 'Status' options inside the database**. Using fixed strings like this is *really* bad practice. Especially since you probably need the *same* options when *editing*, or *adding* new students

Comment: I have my 'Status' options in my database but as an integer.

Comment: @rukshiin do you have a separate table for the statuses (as described in my answer)?

Comment: Nice One it helps :-)